# Microsoft WPF Ribbon (Oct/2010 release) - Binding to content

Tags: .net, wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control

I have an instance of the [Microsoft Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) within my application, and I am trying to bind the content of a RibbonGroup to a collection of images within my ViewModel in such a way that (a) the image is displayed as the large image of a RibbonButton and (b) when the user clicks one of the RibbonButton controls, the corresponding image is set as the CurrentItem of the collection (currently, an EntityCollection).

I have tried various means, based loosely around the following...

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="viewButtonTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ribbon:RibbonButton Grid.Row="0" Label="{Binding Path=ImageType.Description}"
                                                 LargeImageSource="{Binding Path=ImageData, Converter={StaticResource BinaryJpegToImageSourceConverter}}"
                                                 Command=""/>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" MaxWidth="30" Source="{Binding Path=ImageData, Converter={StaticResource BinaryJpegToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=ImageType.Description}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="View">
    <ListBox Name="imageList" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource viewButtonTemplate}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

But all to no avail! I simply cannot get the RibbonButton to act as I want. Note: The additional image control within the template actually allows it to work; it seems to be related to getting the ListView to recognise the click of the RibbonButton.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented a WPF application that uses the Ribbon control with the MVVM pattern, but my approach was to create a set of navigation interfaces that I bound the ribbon to. I also leveraged styling of the ribbon elements to control the data binding which I believe may help you accomplish what you are after.

After binding your Ribbon control to the view model, you can populate your tabs and their child groups such that the images you want to display will be rendered, and then specify the ICommand on the view model you wish to be executed when a group is selected. This command would call a method to set the current item of the collection.

**Ribbon Control Styles:**

```
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- RibbonMenuItem -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonMenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding Image}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipTitle" Value="{Binding ToolTipTitle}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipDescription" Value="{Binding ToolTipDescription}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipImageSource" Value="{Binding ToolTipImage}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipFooterTitle" Value="{Binding ToolTipFooterTitle}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipFooterDescription" Value="{Binding ToolTipFooterDescription}" />
        <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipFooterImageSource" Value="{Binding ToolTipFooterImage}" />
        <Setter Property="KeyTipService.KeyTip" Value="{Binding KeyTip}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeVertically" Value="{Binding IsVerticallyResizable}" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeHorizontally" Value="{Binding IsHorizontallyResizable}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Command}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CommandParameter}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Image}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToolTipImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToolTipFooterImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ribbon:RibbonControlService.ToolTipFooterImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- RibbonSplitMenuItem -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonSplitMenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ribbon:RibbonMenuItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderQuickAccessToolBarId" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        <Setter Property="QuickAccessToolBarId" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.Command}" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderKeyTip" Value="{Binding KeyTip}" />
        <Setter Property="KeyTip" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.KeyTip}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipTitle" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipTitle}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipDescription" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipDescription}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipImageSource" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipImage}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipFooterTitle" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipFooterTitle}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipFooterDescription" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipFooterDescription}" />
        <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipFooterImageSource" Value="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipFooterImage}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DropDownButtonData.ToolTipFooterImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="DropDownToolTipFooterImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- RibbonApplicationMenuItem -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ribbon:RibbonMenuItem}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Level" Value="Middle">
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{Binding Image}" />
                <Setter Property="KeyTipService.KeyTip" Value="{Binding KeyTip}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ribbon:RibbonSplitMenuItem}}" />

    <!-- RibbonTab -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonTab}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Groups}" />
    </Style>

    <!-- RibbonGroupItem -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}" x:Key="RibbonGroupItemButton">
        <Setter Property="Label" Value="{Binding Label}" />
        <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="{Binding LargeImage}" />
        <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="{Binding SmallImage}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LargeImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="LargeImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SmallImage}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="SmallImageSource" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonControl}"  x:Key="RibbonGroupItemTemplate">
        <ribbon:RibbonButton Style="{StaticResource RibbonGroupItemButton}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- RibbonGroup -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RibbonGroupItemTemplate}" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

**Properties exposed by the view model (data binding):**

```
#region MenuItems
/// <summary>
/// Gets the application menu items.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// A <see cref="SelectableObservableCollection{IMenuItem}"/> that contains 
/// the application menu items. The default value is an <i>empty</i> collection.
/// </value>
public SelectableObservableCollection<IMenuItem> MenuItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_viewModelMenuItems == null)
        {
            _viewModelMenuItems = new SelectableObservableCollection<IMenuItem>();
        }
        return _viewModelMenuItems;
    }
}
private SelectableObservableCollection<IMenuItem> _viewModelMenuItems;
#endregion

#region Tabs
/// <summary>
/// Gets the application navigation tabs.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// A <see cref="SelectableObservableCollection{INavigationTab}"/> that contains 
/// the application navigation tabs. The default value is an <i>empty</i> collection.
/// </value>
public SelectableObservableCollection<INavigationTab> Tabs
{
    get
    {
        if (_viewModelTabs == null)
        {
            _viewModelTabs = new SelectableObservableCollection<INavigationTab>();
        }
        return _viewModelTabs;
    }
}
private SelectableObservableCollection<INavigationTab> _viewModelTabs;
#endregion
```

**View (Ribbon XAML):**

```
<ribbon:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tabs}">

    <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu 
            Margin="0, 5, 0, 0"
            LargeImageSource="/MyApp;component/Resources/Images/ApplicationMenu.png" 
            SmallImageSource="/MyApp;component/Resources/Icons/ApplicationMenu.png" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" 
        >
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton 
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2" BorderBrush="#B8114EAF" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=Shutdown}"
                        Label="Exit" ToolTipTitle="Quit application" KeyTip="X" 
                        SmallImageSource="/MyApp;component/Resources/Icons/Exit.png" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.FooterPaneContent>

        </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
    </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>

</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

**Navigation Interfaces:**

```
public interface IMenuItem : ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region Command
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the command associated with the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ISurrogateCommand"/> associated with the menu item.
    /// </value>
    ISurrogateCommand Command
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region CommandParameter
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parameter to pass to the command associated with the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The parameter to pass to the <see cref="Command"/> associated with the menu item.
    /// </value>
    object CommandParameter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Header
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item that labels the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The item that labels the menu item.
    /// </value>
    object Header
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Image
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the image that is displayed on the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ImageSource"/> that is displayed on the menu item.
    /// </value>
    ImageSource Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsCheckable
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the menu item can be checked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the menu item can be checked; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    bool IsCheckable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsChecked
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the menu item is checked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the menu item is checked; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    bool IsChecked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsHorizontallyResizable
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the menu item can be resized horizontally.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the menu item can be resized horizontally; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    bool IsHorizontallyResizable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsVerticallyResizable
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the menu item can be resized vertically.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the menu item can be resized vertically; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </value>
    bool IsVerticallyResizable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Items
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the child menu items for the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="SelectableObservableCollection{IMenuItem}"/> collection that contains the child menu items for the menu item.
    /// </value>
    SelectableObservableCollection<IMenuItem> Items
    {
        get;
    }
    #endregion

    #region KeyTip
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the text to use for the menu item key tip.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The text to use for the menu item key tip.
    /// </value>
    string KeyTip
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipDescription
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The description for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </value>
    string ToolTipDescription
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipFooterDescription
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The description for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </value>
    string ToolTipFooterDescription
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipFooterImage
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the image for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ImageSource"/> for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </value>
    ImageSource ToolTipFooterImage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipFooterTitle
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the title for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The title for the menu item tooltip footer.
    /// </value>
    string ToolTipFooterTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipImage
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the image for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ImageSource"/> for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </value>
    ImageSource ToolTipImage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ToolTipTitle
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the title for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The title for the menu item tooltip.
    /// </value>
    string ToolTipTitle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface INavigationTab : ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region Groups
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the groups for the navigation tab.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="SelectableObservableCollection{INavigationTabGroup}"/> collection that contains 
    /// the navigation groups for the navigation tab.
    /// </value>
    SelectableObservableCollection<INavigationTabGroup> Groups
    {
        get;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Header
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item that labels the navigation tab.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The item that labels the navigation tab.
    /// </value>
    object Header
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface INavigationTabGroup : ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region Header
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item that labels the navigation tab group.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The item that labels the navigation tab group.
    /// </value>
    object Header
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Items
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the items for the navigation tab group.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="SelectableObservableCollection{INavigationTabGroupItem}"/> collection that contains 
    /// the navigation items for the navigation tab group.
    /// </value>
    SelectableObservableCollection<INavigationTabGroupItem> Items
    {
        get;
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface INavigationTabGroupItem : ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region Command
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the command associated with the navigation tab group item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ISurrogateCommand"/> associated with the navigation tab group item.
    /// </value>
    ISurrogateCommand Command
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region CommandParameter
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parameter to pass to the command associated with the navigation tab group item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The parameter to pass to the <see cref="Command"/> associated with the navigation tab group item.
    /// </value>
    object CommandParameter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Label
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item that labels the navigation tab group item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The item that labels the navigation tab group item.
    /// </value>
    object Label
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region LargeImage
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the large image that is displayed by the navigation tab group item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ImageSource"/> that represents the large image that is displayed 
    /// by the navigation tab group item.
    /// </value>
    ImageSource LargeImage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region SmallImage
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the small image that is displayed by the navigation tab group item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The <see cref="ImageSource"/> that represents the small image that is displayed 
    /// by the navigation tab group item.
    /// </value>
    ImageSource SmallImage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Here is an example of the view model populating its Tabs collection:**

```
private void AddTabs()
{
    INavigationTab homeTab              = new NavigationTab(Properties.Resources.Shell_Tab_Home_Header);

    INavigationTabGroup generalGroup    = new NavigationTabGroup(Properties.Resources.Shell_TabGroup_General_Header);
    generalGroup.Items.Add(
        new NavigationTabGroupItem
        {
            Label               = Properties.Resources.Shell_StartPage_Header,
            LargeImage          = GetImage("/MyApp;component/Resources/Images/Home.png"),
            CommandParameter    = this,
            Command             = this.DisplayStartPage
        }
    );
    generalGroup.Items.Add(
        new NavigationTabGroupItem
        {
            Label       = Properties.Resources.Shell_Settings_Header,
            SmallImage  = GetImage("/MyApp;component/Resources/Icons/Settings.png")
        }
    );
    generalGroup.Items.Add(
        new NavigationTabGroupItem
        {
            Label       = Properties.Resources.Shell_UserInformation_Header,
            SmallImage  = GetImage("/MyApp;component/Resources/Icons/UserInformation.png")
        }
    );
    generalGroup.Items.Add(
        new NavigationTabGroupItem
        {
            Label       = Properties.Resources.Shell_About_Header,
            SmallImage  = GetImage("/MyApp;component/Resources/Icons/About.png"),
            Command     = this.AboutApplication
        }
    );

    homeTab.Groups.Add(generalGroup);

    this.Tabs.Add(homeTab);
}
```

**Also, I initially had some problems binding image sources, but found a solution by using Freeze. Here is an example:**

```
// Build navigation tab
this.Tab    = new NavigationTab(Properties.Resources.Module_Tab_Header);

var administrationImage = GetImage("/MyApp;component/Resources/Images/Administration.png");
administrationImage.Freeze();

INavigationTabGroup administrationGroup = new NavigationTabGroup(Properties.Resources.Module_TabGroup_Administration_Header);
administrationGroup.Items.Add(
    new NavigationTabGroupItem
    {
        Label               = Properties.Resources.Module_StartPage_Header,
        LargeImage          = administrationImage
    }
);

/// <summary>
/// Gets an image resource in the assembly for the specified path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The relative path to the image resource.</param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="System.Windows.Media.ImageSource"/> located at the specified <paramref name="path"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <example>
/// Path: <i>/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Icons/MyIcon.png</i>
/// </example>
protected static System.Windows.Media.ImageSource GetImage(string path)
{
    return new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(
            new Uri(String.Format(null, "pack://application:,,,{0}", path))
    );
}
```

Hope this helps you with your binding issues.

Comment: Whilst this is a fantastic answer (+1), I am not sure as to how it will fit with my requirement. In my case I have a collection of images that I want to show in buttons on the ribbon and in the main area of the window I show one of those images. When the user clicks one of the buttons, I want the selected image to show in the main window. I do not know how many images there will be at any given time and (currently) I am not using ICommand to do this. I simply need the click of the button to be recognised by the ListView control so that it selects in the same way as if I simply show the image.